# Register touch on passing through multiple UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am trying to detect touches on passing through multiple UIViews in an iOS application written in Swift.

Following image should clarify the user interaction:

[image: Touch moving through multiple UIViews]

Each of the colored tiles is a `UIView`.
When the finger is pressed on the purple tile, I can use the `touchesBegan` to register the touch. Then I can track the finger via `touchesMoved` to cancel the touch when it moves from the purple tile into the brown tile.

Now, basically I want to fire the `touchesBegan` method on the brown tile until the finger goes into the blue tile. Again, this should fire the `touchesEnded` of brown and `touchesBegan` on the blue one.

How can I implement this in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `UIPenGesture` ...

and in selector method detect area of touch and do color change on tile as per requirement ...

Comment: usefull tutorial  http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/dragging-views-with-gestures ...

Comment: Then the Views would need to know of each other. I hoped that the touchesBegan will fire when you just move over a UIView so that they don't need to know each other.

Comment: add Gesture on parent view of all this tiles, and check that touch coordinate contents in brown tile or not ... and you can get touch state so starting ending can be detected ...